# Bind the Latest values to Form

Tags: angular

i am using formgroup and form control in my form,
when the user page is open i have binded the values those are populating in fields

but when i save the form the fields are coming with empty values.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.contactDetailsForm = this.fb.group({
      personalInfoForm: this.initPersonalInfo(),
      financialInfoForm: this.initFinancialInfo()
    });

    initPersonalInfo() {
    return this.fb.group({
      prospectFname: [''],
      prospectLname: [''],
      prospectPreferredname: [''],
      prospect_dob: [],
      prospect_addr1: [''],
      prospect_city: [''],
      prospect_st: [''],
      prospect_zip: ['']
    });
  }

  initFinancialInfo() {
    return this.fb.group({
      another_nasd_firm: [''],
      another_nasd_firm_name: [''],
      selfEmployed: [''],
      work_status_change: [''],
    });
  }
  }

  this._contactFilterService
      .getContactDetailsDataById(this.selectedContact, this.brokerId)
      .subscribe(result => {
        if (result) {
          this.contactdetail = result;
          this.prospectId = result.prospectId;
          this.setPatchValues(result);
          Here i want to setPatch values to the fields
            prospectFname: [''], // bind the latest values to form field
            prospectLname: [''],

        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have nested object arrays and if the object properties in your data matches the form controls in your form, you can simply do:

```ts
setPatchValues(result) {
  this.contactDetailsForm.setValue(result)
}
```

Otherwise you need to set the values long hand, each formcontrol separately in the same manner with `setValue`, for example:

```ts
this.contactDetailsForm.get('personalInfoForm.prospectFname').setValue(result.someProp)
```

or with group:

```ts
this.contactDetailsForm.get('personalInfoForm').setValue({
  prospectFname: result.someProp,
  // ....
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 const personalInfoFormModel = this.personalInfoForm.value;               
 const financialInfoFormModel = this.financialInfoForm.value;
```

This is how you can get the latest personalInfoForm and financialInfoForm

```
        prospectFname = personalInfoFormModel.prospectFname; // bind the latest values for form
        prospectLname = personalInfoFormModel.prospectLname;
```

or simply `this.personalInfoForm = personalInfoFormModel;`

Comment: i want to set latest data to the form group fields (from controls)

Comment: See the edit..once you get the form model you can assign the latest values as you did in for initialization. Is that what you want  to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

In ngOnInit(), set the initial value of the form fields with variables.

```
    prospectFname: new FormControl(formOne.prospectFname)
```

And, in the setPatchValues method, edit these variables with the latest values.